# Does all algebraic developments also work work with complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I stumbled on this simple question in my mathbook:

**Show that the equality:** $$\left( \frac{z(z+1)}{2} \right)^2 + (z+1)^3 = \left( \frac{(z+1)(z+2)}{2} \right)^2$$

for all z $\in \mathbb{C}$

Now this is quite easy to show, but I wonder if all algebraic developments of this kind also holds true for complex numbers?

From my understanding they do, but I am not sure if I can explain why they do...

**My attempt at an explanation:** This is true for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, since when $z$ is only $\in \mathbb{R}$ is a special case where $Im{(z)} = 0.$

This explanation does not seem 100% water tight to me... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got access to some higher level machinery, you can use the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem). Since the equality is true on $\Bbb R$, it is automatically true on all of $\Bbb C$ since polynomials are entire functions.

In fact, it is this very theorem that is almost always used to formalize the fact that functions which are equal on $\Bbb R$, **stay** equal on $\Bbb C$, making the casual observation you have made rigorous with mathematics rather than hocus pocus or hand-waving.

If you're not into that, or just haven't learned the identity theorem, then it's still not hard:  just FOIL things out and subtract one side from the other. The definition of equality is

> $$a=b\iff a-b=0$$

which you can easily check by combining like terms.

Comment: I could be wrong, but surely you can't need the whole structure of holomorphicity to show that equalities that hold in $\Bbb R[x]$ also hold in $\Bbb C[x]$?

Comment: @gperez the OP seems to want this to be equality as functions, not formal polynomial equivalences. You're right, but I have already addressed that question in the second half of my answer. The first half of my answer is intended to show that his intuition is backed up by a theorem.

Comment: Ok then. I really did want to make sure though. I guess what you're saying is that he can be reassured that this will work with other types of functions as well.

Comment: As a follow-up question, could you possibly prove the identity theorem for the special case of equality when restricted to $\Bbb R$, just by using the algebraic fact that holds in polynomials?

Comment: @GPerez I mean, if it holds on polynomials, the local Taylor series imply $\epsilon$ closeness for arbitrary functions as well, in fact that's inherent in the identity theorem proof. The point of analytic functions is that they are exactly those with local power series.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your comments, much appreciated!